# Read specific parts of File in java

Tags: java

I need to read a file with the following structure [Structure of File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k9Men.png)

In the file I have firstly to separate the **deps** content and the **outs** content.

After that separation I need to separate the blocks that start with **-md5** until I find another one.

For example, in the picture I have 2 blocks for the **deps** part and for the **outs** part I have 3 blocks.

Currently I am using **LineNumberReader** to firstly separate **deps** and **outs** and then I create an **ArrayList** of the **deps** content and the **outs** content, but I think this is not very good since I need to separate next the blocks that are started by **-md5** in case I have more than one.

[This is What I pretend](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jJtvi.png)

How can I do this in a better way?
Thanks for any help.

Comment: Have you tried using a third party project like Jackson, have a look at:
https://stackabuse.com/reading-and-writing-yaml-files-in-java-with-jackson/
This presumes your project is a maven one.

Comment: Thanks for the help @BillNaylor! I will try implement that way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [syntax](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/YAMLSyntax.html) of the file type you are trying to read is [YAML](https://yaml.org/), so if you need to parse the file and map it to an already defined class, you can use [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson).

Then the mapping process is as simple as:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper(new YAMLFactory());
try {
        YourCustomClass obj = mapper.readValue(new File("YourFilePath.yaml"), YourCustomClass.class);
        System.out.println(obj.getProperty());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

BTW, you can install Jackson using maven if you are using so.

---

Comment: Thanks for the help Abdulrahman Hashem! I will implement that way